# How to upload a image to azure using jmeter given the webservice in JSON format

Tags: jmeter

JSON webservice is provided. How to upload a image to azure using jmeter given the webservice in JSON format.

I have to add JSON web service to Jmeter manually. It works in POSTMAN to uplaod a file to Azure container. Same webservice is required to be added in Jmeter manually. I am stuck at a point in Jmeter where Upload file path (local) could be provided, but the destination parameter how to provide. MIME Type can be given. Also, complete JSON body if provided in Jmeter then How to add file manually with the request. Please guide. Inputs I have is URL & Json body structure. And, I have to pass image with this request in Jmeter so that I can go ahead with performance test further.

Comment: Please clarify your question...

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a comprehensive answer you need to include the request format your Azure endpoint expects.

In easier cases it is just enough to record your file upload event using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) - just make sure to copy your .json file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation prior to uploading so JMeter could detect it.

In harder cases you will need to construct your request manually like it's described in [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) article, the example assumes using [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) however you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I have to add JSON web service to Jmeter manually. It works in POSTMAN to uplaod a file to Azure container. Same webservice is required to be added in Jmeter manually. I am stuck at a point in Jmeter where Upload file path (local) could be provided, but the destination parameter how to provide. MIME Type can be given. Also, complete JSON body if provided in Jmeter then How to add file manually with the request. Please guide.  Inputs I have is URL & Json body structure. And, I have to pass image with this request in Jmeter so that I can go ahead with performance test further. Thank you.